# Best Light server (Linux + Web server + Database) for Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, web, server

I would like to install a web server with a database on a Raspberry Pi (little computer). 
The computer has only 1GB RAM.

I want to know what is the best combination: Linux distribution and web server and DBMS to run the local server with multiple users with minimal latency, I will use PHP on the server. And what are the best settings for good performance and to not have bugs (memory usage, disable plugin, disable service, etc)?

I thought a light Debian , a lighttpd server and SQLite for the database. Is this is a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Lighttpd` + `SQLite` is a great choice. For the linux distro, Debian is good but you could also look at CentOS or something like [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/welcome.html), although I'm not sure of the compatibility with the Pi. Obviously, you can't go wrong with [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/)

If you want to use this in production and get more stable performance, you could get a few more Pi's and set them up in a [cluster](http://raspberrywebserver.com/raspberrypicluster/raspberry-pi-cluster.html).